# Is it possible to know which key is being used when an SSH account is logged in

Tags: bash, ssh

In a bash script I would like to know which key is being used for current login. Any ideas how to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to prepend the keys in authorized_keys with a command="< some script >". Then have that script set an environment variable to go with that key (or give it as a parameter to the command). Oh and don't forget to have the script start a shell. So something allong the lines of

```
#!/bin/sh
export SomeVariable=$1
bash
```